# ¿como validar que solo sea minimo un digito y maximo dos digitos'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas a todos. Tengo un campo temperatura y solo como minimo 5 grado y maximo 30 grados. Lo que ven es mi validacion pero no la cantidad. Podrian ayudarme.

```
      <label for="rep_legal">Temperatura</label>
      <input type="text" id="txt_temperatura" class="solo-numero">

     $('.solo-numero').keyup(function () {
         this.value = (this.value + '').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

     });
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 incluye un input numerico, que ademas de ser más amigable (mejor interacción del usuario con el control), te permite definir valores mínimos y máximos.

```html
<label for="temperatura">Temperatura</label>
<input id="txt_temperatura" type="number" name="temperatura" min="5" max="30" placeholder="5 a 30">
```

No olvides definir el *DOCTYPE* al inicio de tu archivo HTML para usar HTML5: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Puedes ver mas opciones en: [HTML5 number input: Un nuevo campo de tipo numérico en el form](http://www.anerbarrena.com/html5-number-input-form-1469/)

Answer (score 0):

creo que eso sería mejor validarlo con html, lo siguiente te funcionaría

`<input type="number" id="temp" min="1" max="99">`

Comment: por que el name quantity.

Comment: No tiene sentido ponerle "quantity"

Comment: quantity solo por que se trataba de cantidad numerica pero ya lo quite ya que no es necesaria siquiera

Answer (score 0):

Adicional a lo que te comentaron puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="99" minlength="1" maxlength="2" />
```

Con esto adicional a que limitas los valores limitas el numero de caracteres en tu formulario.

Saludos.